# What is the significance of defining the partial derivative as a one-sided limit or a two-sided limit?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function. We can define the partial derivative of f with respect to its first argument using either a two-sided limit ($h\to 0$)

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x_1+h,x_2,\ldots,x_n)-f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)}{h}$$
or a one-sided limit ($h\to 0^+$)

$$\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{f(x_1+h,x_2,\ldots,x_n)-f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)}{h}$$

to see it as a directional derivative in the direction of the basis vector $e_1$.

Are there any peculiarities of one defintion vs the other? Do some interesting theroems/intuitions about differentiabiltiy change drastically?

Answer (score 2):

You can consider the function $f(x)=|x|$ (of a single variable) and notice how the two definitions give different answers. Adding additional variables doesn't change anything.

Comment: I am aware that the two formulations give different outputs. I am interested in something more abstract; how does this affect theorems and definitions "downstream" of the definition.

Comment: An actual answer might be: the chain rule does not hold any longer.